# Update existing word document from SharePoint via code

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, workflow, event-handlers, word

I'd like to insert a line of text into an existing Word document that is stored in a document library. Would this be possible to do through an event or workflow? If so, how would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first write the code to modify the Word document. Assuming that you're using Office 2010, you can use the Open XML SDK, you can find specific instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478255%28v=office.14%29).

Now you have to find a place to trigger this code, and you could do an [EventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx) or develop a workflow action. If you only need to do this whenever the document is added to the library the EventReciever will be the easier solution.